# PyInstaller can't build a 'Firebase Firestore python file' in linux

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, pyinstaller

When I am trying to build a linux executable file it builds successfully but when i try to run the executable file it shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 341, in get_data
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEI4f5JfX/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem'
Exception ignored in: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.ssl_roots_override_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 341, in get_data
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEI4f5JfX/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem'
E1122 03:58:17.060399901   23697 ssl_utils.cc:550]           assertion failed: pem_root_certs != nullptr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

python file
**main.py**

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db, firestore

# firebase app setup
cred = credentials.Certificate({ 
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "project-216t8",
........
....
..
})
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)


def fetch_data():
    doc_ref = DocCollection_ref   
    docs= doc_ref.get()
    if docs.exists:
         docs = docs.to_dict()   
         print(f'Document data: {docs.to_dict()}')
    else:
     print(u'No such document!')

fetch_data()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This solution worked for me**.

You will need to create a pyinstaller hook for packages that depend on setuptools' get_distribution() to obtain metadata information about the package.

Create a hook file in some hooks directory. The file name should be `hook-<modulename>.py` for pyinstaller to find it properly (i.e. `hook-gcloud.py`).

**Solution :**
Create two **hook** files:

- hook-gcloud.py
- hook-grpc.py

In **hook-gcloud.py** write below code and save it :

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('gcloud')
```

In **hook-grpc.py** write below code and save it :

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files ( 'grpc' )
```

Now copy and paste the both files to **/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/** directory.